# How do I add image to Qualtrics survey for social media posts?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, qualtrics

I am trying to post a Qualtrics link to social media with a specific image. I understand that for Facebook/LinkedIn to detect the image, I must include the image in the page's meta-tags.

I have added the following code into the header of the survey:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://universityofalabama.az1.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_03oSvYXLNUaQi2N"/>
```

The problem is, this code is showing up in the header of an iframe on the page, not in the header of the page itself. The Facebook tool doesn't see it. Is there any way to fix this? I tried to use Javascript (although I've seen mixed advice on whether that will work) and it didn't work.

I would really appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are out of luck.  The meta tag has to go in the `<head>` and there is no way to do that. You can set the values of the title and description meta tags through Survey Options. All you can do is submit a feature request through Qualtrics Support to add an image option to the Survey Options.

The reason the tag you added is in a frame is because you are in preview mode. It doesn't matter though because even if the tag wasn't in a frame, it still wouldn't be in the `<head>` and Facebook wouldn't recognize it.

JavaScript only applies to the client side browser, so it couldn't possibly help in this instance.

Comment: Thank you T. Gibbons. I am wondering if the best solution (assuming I am not willing to give up having an image in the social media post) is to set up a webpage that re-directs to the survey, and include the desired tags including images there. Can you think of any other options?

Comment: @EmMa - A redirect is a good idea, but I don't know if a straight redirect would work. Facebook may follow it and give you the same result as before. You may need to put the survey link on your redirect page then have JavaScript click it for it to work.